# Inclusion-Exclusion principle / Coupon Collector

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, inclusion-exclusion, coupon-collector

Here's the setup to the problem. Assume there are $5$ types of coupons, and you keep collecting coupons until you meet your condition. What is the probability that the number of trials needed to collect all $5$ types of coupons is done in $x$ trials?  In general, is there a closed form for finding the probability of collecting $y_1$ of the 1st type, $y_2$ of the 2nd type, $y_3$ of the 3rd type, $y_4$ of the 4th type, $y_5$ of the 5th type # of coupons in $x$ trials?

What about $C$ types of coupons?  $(y_1,y_2,...,y_C)$

Can there be a closed form?

Comment: Assuming the coupons are equally likely, the probability of collecting 5 types in $x$ trials or fewer is the probability that a function from a set of size $x$ to a set of size 5 is onto. This is a standard inclusion-exclusion problem, and leads to the quantities known as the Stirling numbers.

Comment: Can you take me through a calculation that would use  p = 1/4 ,   and collecting  4 of the 1st, 1 of the 2nd, 1 of the 3rd, and 1 of the 4th for 4 coupons done in 17 trials or fewer? This uses the Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind? Just trying to verify a result I found by simulating.

Comment: The 4 of type 1 makes things complicated.

Comment: Is there a closed form for it though? Ideally I could have a way to figure out chances for collecting any number of any type of coupon in x trials.

Comment: See the comment at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88382/another-generalized-coupon-collectors-problem

Comment: Thanks. This paper seems like it could help.

Comment: If you find it helps, and you can write up some kind of summary and post it here as an answer, that would be very useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83788/discussion-between-swinch-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat.

Comment: Making any progress on that write-up?

Comment: I can’t seem to get the integral mentioned in the paper to converge.

Comment: Maybe that could be another question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934532/coupon-collecting-with-quotas